# Why does Django's ModelForm validation think that this is invalid?

Tags: python, django

I have what looks to me to be a pretty simple setup of model, modelform and a view playing with the two.  The only hitch is that the model has a user property that can't be POSTed to the form, rather it should be populated by `request.user` so I have this:

```
# models.py
class Update(models.Model):
    user         = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="updates")
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, related_name="updates")
    publish      = models.BooleanField(default=True)



class UpdateForm(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=140,
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "blankable"})
    )

    class Meta(NodeForm.Meta):
        model = Update



# views.py
def status(request):

    from myproject.organisations.models import Organisation
    from myproject.feeds.models         import Update, UpdateForm

    stream = 0
    if request.method == "POST":

        o = request.POST.get("organisation")

        if not o or request.user not in Organisation.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get("organisation")).administrators.all():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("ethico.core.views.index"))

        f = UpdateForm(request.POST, instance=Update(user=request.user))

        if f.is_valid():
            stream = f.save()
        else:
            stream = f.errors
    ...
```

Whenever I run this, I *always* get the same error:

```
user: This field is required.
```

I've tried setting `f` with the `initial` attribute using `{"user": 1}` and it still says that it's required.  I've tried passing in a modified POST by copying the `request.POST` into a new variable and modifying that before passing it to UpdateForm but that's ugly.  What am I forgetting here?

Comment: This does not have to be community wiki.

Comment: Sorry about that, clicked on that box without thinking.  Can I remove that status at this point though?

Comment: I don't think so -- but you can just make a new identical question, not community wiki, and delete this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try excluding the user field in the form

```
class UpdateForm(ModelForm):
  name = forms.CharField(
    max_length=140,
    required=False,
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "blankable"})
  )

  class Meta:
    model = Update
    exclude = ("user",)
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#s-using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form

Comment: Wow.  I can't believe that I missed that.  Thank you so much!